# Chrome forgets settings

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

Everytime I start up Chrome, it asks if I want to make it default (which I reply to by "no"). Also, no matter what size of the window I set, it always opens half-screen-wide.

I've tried reinstalling, updating, rebooting and screaming. To no avail.

Other applications behave as expected.

What can be done about it?